# jQuery Accordion multiple level hierarchy issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build the jQuery accordion. On first level it is working fine but on sub level it is not. Can somebody help me to fix the issue?

[here is the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/wo06tfy5/2/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.browse-by-categories ul div').click(function() {
    $('.browse-by-categories ul div').removeClass('on');
    $('.browse-by-categories ul.toggel').slideUp('normal');
    $('.plusMinus').text('+');
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).children('.plusMinus').text('-');
     } 
 });
$('.browse-by-categories ul li div').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
});
$('.browse-by-categories ul.toggel').hide();
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just adjusted your Fiddle a bit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/wo06tfy5/5/)

```
$(".menu, .submenu").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("menu") && 
         $(this).next(".toggel").find("div.submenu").hasClass("on"))
    {
        $(this).next(".toggel").find("div.submenu").next(".toggel").slideUp();
        $(this).next(".toggel").find(".plusMinus").text('+');
        $(this).next(".toggel").find("div.submenu").toggleClass("on");
    }
    $(this).next(".toggel").slideUp();
    $(this).find('.plusMinus').text('+');

  }
  else {
    $(this).next(".toggel").slideDown();
    $(this).find('.plusMinus').text('-');

  }
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

And added classes "menu" and "submenu" to the divs, so it's easier to identify the slides.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Plus/Minus is not working. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Sure, just added plus/minus here: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/wo06tfy5/4/  (took only care of the multiple level slides before)